# Unable to launch appium 1.9.0 using bat file

Tags: appium-android

I would like to know how to launch appium 1.9.0 using a bat file.

I used the line below but it's not launching.

> "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\lib\appium.js"

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your path is correct. I have appium 1.9.0 and I have node.exe in the appium folder.

My commands in .bat file goes like this and it works

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe" "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\bin\appium.js"